# How to convert the old non-tree packages in tree packages in pharo 3?

Tags: pharo

After the last update of Pharo 3, when I open  the System browser I see a tree structure. All items in this tree follow the name convention of -xxxx for example:
Athens-Cairo-Paints is inside of Athens-Cairo

[image: browser athens cairo]

But the package on my project (and in others packages) doesn't follow this convention.

How can I see my project packages as a tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree works like this:

- Each package is a root
- Anything in a 'Root-Xyz' category shows up as a node under the root

In your case, I'm assuming that by "my project... doesn't follow this convention" you mean that you have multiple packages like:

- MyProjectPackage
- MyProjectOtherPackage

In that case, there is no way to see them in a tree. In fact, there is no way to see a whole project in a tree no matter how they are named, unless the project is all in one package, which follows the naming convention internally. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that packages (Monticello ones) are roots and then categories act as leafs. In the new version category is called "tag". If you right-click a node you can either promote it to package or demote it ti tag (depending on what current status it has now)